# display JSON results on aspx site a certain way

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, json

I am trying to format an output from JSON in a particular way on my aspx site:
[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ves3j/) shows roughly what I am attempting. However I want space between top and bottom div, and also a maximum of 3 divs in each row.

I am retrieving a list from Sharepoint using ListData.svc. My aspx file looks like this:

```
<%@ Page CodeBehind="l2Content.aspx.cs" Language="C#" %>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://server:port" + "/Projects/1/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Projectlist?$select=ID,Title,Project_typeValue,Project_heading,Publish_infoscreen&$filter=Project_typeValue%20eq%20%27TYPE1%27",
            method: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            headers: { "accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
            success: function (data) {
                $('#projectList').empty();                   
                $.each(data.d.results, function(index, item) {                                                                    
                        $('#projectList').append("<li>" + "<h2>" +  item.Project_heading + "</h2>" + item.Title+ + "</li>");                      
                });             
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(error));
            }
        });   
});
</script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<meta name="WebPartPageExpansion" content="full" />
<title></title>
</head>
  <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
       <div id="projectList"></div>
     </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

JSON output:

```
    JSON
      d
        results
          {}
            ID=1
            Project_heading=Heading1
            Project_typeValue=TYPE1
            Publish_infoscreen=True
            Title=Testproject1
```

This is what is supposed to happen:
I am retrieving a list of projects - each of these projects has a property called "Project_heading" attached to it. I wish to create one div for each unique Project_heading, and under this, list all of the projects with that particular project heading.

I thought I could use something like:

```
success: function (data) {
            $('#projectList').empty();
            var projHeadings = [];
            $.each(data.d.results, function (index, item) {

                if ($.inArray(item.Project_heading, projHeadings) == -1) {
                    projHeadings.push(item.Project_heading);
                }

            for (var i = 0, l = projHeadings.length; i < l; i++) {
                var Pitem = projHeadings[i];
                $('#projectHeadingWrapper').append("<div><h1>" + Pitem + "</h1>    </div>");
            }
            });
```

As you probably can tell, I am very new to this and any help is greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:**
Sorry for poor explanation, here I have constructed some dummy data which shows what I want:

from JSON:

```
{
"d" : {
"results": [
{
"__metadata": {
"uri": "http://server:port/Projects/1/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Projectlist(1)", "etag": "W/\"2\"", "type": "Microsoft.SharePoint.DataService.ProjectlistItem"
}, "Title": "TestProject1", "Publish_infoscreen": true, "Project_typeValue": "TYPE1", "Project_heading": "Investments", "ID": 1
}, {
"__metadata": {
"uri": "http://server:port/Projects/1/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Projectlist(2)", "etag": "W/\"2\"", "type": "Microsoft.SharePoint.DataService.ProjectlistItem"
}, "Title": "Testproject2", "Publish_infoscreen": false, "Project_typeValue": "TYPE1", "Project_heading": "Investments", "ID": 2
}, {
"__metadata": {
"uri": "http://server:port/Projects/1/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Projectlist(3)", "etag": "W/\"2\"", "type": "Microsoft.SharePoint.DataService.ProjectlistItem"
}, "Title": "Project x1", "Publish_infoscreen": true, "Project_typeValue": "TYPE1", "Project_heading": "Sales", "ID": 3
}, {
"__metadata": {
"uri": "http://server:port/Projects/1/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Projectlist(4)", "etag": "W/\"2\"", "type": "Microsoft.SharePoint.DataService.ProjectlistItem"
}, "Title": "Project x2", "Publish_infoscreen": true, "Project_typeValue": "TYPE1", "Project_heading": "Sales", "ID": 4
}, {
"__metadata": {
"uri": "http://server:port/Projects/1/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Projectlist(5)", "etag": "W/\"2\"", "type": "Microsoft.SharePoint.DataService.ProjectlistItem"
}, "Title": "Project x3", "Publish_infoscreen": false, "Project_typeValue": "TYPE1", "Project_heading": "Sales", "ID": 5
}, {
"__metadata": {
"uri": "http://server:port/Projects/1/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Projectlist(6)", "etag": "W/\"2\"", "type": "Microsoft.SharePoint.DataService.ProjectlistItem"
}, "Title": "Project y1", "Publish_infoscreen": true, "Project_typeValue": "TYPE1", "Project_heading": "Offers", "ID": 6
}
]
}
}
```

which I would like to look like in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aEfnB/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var results = new Array();

        var test1 = new Object();
        test1.Title = "TestProject1";
        test1.Project_heading = "Investments";
        results.push(test1);

        var test2 = new Object();
        test2.Title = "TestProject2";
        test2.Project_heading = "Investments";
        results.push(test2);

        var test3 = new Object();
        test3.Title = "Project x1";
        test3.Project_heading = "Sales";
        results.push(test3);

        var test4 = new Object();
        test4.Title = "TestProject3";
        test4.Project_heading = "Investments";
        results.push(test4);

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.projectRow').empty();

            $.each(results, function (index, item) {
                var itemExist = false;
                $.each($('.projectRow').find('h1'), function (index1, item1) {
                    if (item1.innerHTML == item.Project_heading) {
                        itemExist = true;
                        $(item1).parent().append("<h3>" + item.Title + "</h3");
                    }
                });
                if (itemExist == false)
                    $('.projectRow').append("<div class='projectHeadingDiv left'><li><h1>" + item.Project_heading + "</h1><h3>" + item.Title + "</h3></li></div>");
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .projectHeadingDiv
        {
            width: 900px;
            list-style: none;
            vertical-align: middle;
            background-color: gray;
            padding: 30px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .left
        {
            margin-left: 20px;
            float: left;
            width: 200px;
        }
        .projectRow div
        {
            vertical-align: top;
            padding-top: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="projectHeadingWrapper">
        <div class="projectRow">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Note : Only replace "results" with "data.d.results" in above code snippet.

Comment: Won't this make a div for every Project_heading? In my situation many projects have the same project heading. I was thinking more in the lines of collecting all the project with the same project heading in the same div. Won't this if I have x JSON results, create the same amount of divs?

Comment: If two object have same project heading and project title is different then which type of UI you want?

Comment: Title would be the name of the actual project. "Project_heading" would function like a group, where the same types of projects can be listed together. I am sorry if I am being confusing (english is my second language). Think of Project_heading as a category if you will, and the project title refers to the name of the actual project.

Comment: Can you please provide your sample/dummy data? Based on data which type of UI you wants?

Comment: Yes, I have updated my original post. It now shows how I want the result to look like.